# How can I use DataTypes key as arguments

Tags: c, lua, c-preprocessor, variadic-functions, variadic-macros

I have a macro that works as expected, but I want to make some changes to make it cleaner to use.

```
#define FuncCreate(func_name, func, ...) \
   int func_name(lua_State *ms) { \
     func(__VA_ARGS__); \
     return 0; \
   }


FuncCreate(appEvent, app_event, lua_touserdata(ms, 1), lua_tointeger(ms, 2), lua_tostring(ms, 3));
FuncCreate(GdEvent, gd_event, lua_touserdata(ms, 1), lua_touserdata(ms, 2), lua_tostring(ms, 3), lua_tointeger(ms, 4), lua_tostring(ms, 5));
```

I want to change the way I use arguments in the macro

I want to make use of key from data types e.g.

```
FuncCreate(appEvent, app_event, struct, int, const char*);
FuncCreate(GdEvent, gd_event, struct, int, const char*, int, const char*);
```

How can the macro take for example get the names

**`struct`** pass as argument to **`func`** the lua_touserdata
pass **`int`** as an argument to **`func`** or lua_tointeger

Would it be better to create a variadic function?
How can I do this ? Remembering that I want to use the key name of the data types

Comment: For your proposed improvement to the macro, how do you want someone to call `appEvent()`?

Comment: @jxh Yes, I will need to call the created functions

Comment: But how? What do you expect the caller to pass in?

Comment: @jxh This function generated by the macro will be added to a `lua_register` function in the c code to be used within the lua file. Example `lua_register(L, "AppEvent", appEvent);`

Comment: `struct,` What struct??

Comment: @KamilCuk `struct` must return `lua_touserdata` as an argument in the struct macro will work as a string

Comment: struct is not a valid type. `How can I use DataTypes key as arguments` What are "DataTypes" exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can the macro take for example get the names

You can use a _Generic to overload over type. Then you can overload a macro over variable number of arguments to pass each function to proper callback.

```
#define LUA_TO(x) _Generic((x) \
    , int: lua_tointeger \
    , const char *: lua_tostring \
    , void *: lua_touserdata \
    )

#define LUA_TO_FOREACH_1(ms,i,a)      LUA_TO(a)(ms,i)
#define LUA_TO_FOREACH_2(ms,i,a,...)  LUA_TO_FOREACH_1(ms,i,a)  LUA_TO_FOREACH_1(ms,i+1,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LUA_TO_FOREACH_3(ms,i,a,...)  LUA_TO_FOREACH_1(ms,i,a)  LUA_TO_FOREACH_2(ms,i+1,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LUA_TO_FOREACH_4(ms,i,a,...)  LUA_TO_FOREACH_1(ms,i,a)  LUA_TO_FOREACH_3(ms,i+1,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LUA_TO_FOREACH_N(_4,_3,_2,_1,N,...) LUA_TO_FOREACH##N
#define LUA_TO_FOREACH(ms,...)  LUA_TO_FOREACH_N(__VA_ARGS__,_4,_3,_2,_1,__VA_ARGS__)(ms,1,__VA_ARGS__)

#define FUNCCREATE(func_name, func, ...) \
   int func_name(lua_State *ms) { \
     func(LUA_TO_FOREACH(ms,__VA_ARGS__)); \
     return 0; \
   }

FUNCCREATE(appEvent, app_event, int, const char*);
// Results in: int appEvent(lua_State *ms) { app_event(_Generic((int) , int: lua_tointeger , const char *: lua_tostring , void *: lua_touserdata )(ms,1) _Generic((const char*) , int: lua_tointeger , const char *: lua_tostring , void *: lua_touserdata )(ms,1 +1)); return 0; };
```

> Would it be better to create a variadic function?

C programming is statically typed and does not have reflection capability. Using a variadic function would lose the information about types, which seems to be of interest here.

Overall, it would be better *not* to write such code. In C, you would type everything out, line by line. Writing such macro expansions to generate functions results in really hard to maintain and unreadable code that no one is ever able to fix or change later.

Comment: To OP: +100. The last paragraph is critical. Code is written once and read many times. When you make a complex nested macro, you are effectively adding syntax to the C language for any reader of your code. So you're requiring _all readers forever_ to invest time to learn your language extension and - as @KamilCuk says - deal indirectly with hidden code generated by the cpp. At some point the extra "clean-ness" might boil out to a win, but ime that just about never happens in practice. Your current macro is readable without significant deconstruction. Be happy.